# ReSharper - Possible 'System.NullReferenceException' after Any

Tags: linq, resharper, nullreferenceexception

I'm using ReSharper Ultimate 2016.2, but I have seen this in previous versions as well. ReSharper will give me a warning saying *Possible 'System.NullReferenceException'* when I use `FirstOrDefault` after `Any`. Example below:

```
Foo[] items = GetItems();
var myName = "MyName";
if (items.Any(x => x.Name == myName))
{
    var item = items.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == myName);
    var name = item.Name; // Possible 'System.NullReferenceException'
}
```

Is the warning correct, or is the code above safe?

I know that I can disable the warning, but that's not the point. I want to make sure that there's no chance for that `NullReferenceException` to occur. Since I first check with `Any`, then `FirstOrDefault` should return one item. Or am I missing something?

The code above is simply a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

**UPDATE:**

As mentioned in the comments, the code can be optimized (and simplified). The question is not how to fix the problem in the code. But if there actually can occur a `NullReferenceException`, as ReSharper states?

Comment: No point in using Any then. Just if FirstOrDefault and then check for null on the result

Comment: If you are so sure, why using `OrDefault` and not simply `First`? The tool cannot analyze all code paths and logic.

Comment: @IvanStoev - Yes, I should be able to use `First` instead. But the question is more about if ReSharper actually knows something that I missed. Can there be a `NullReferenceException` in the code? Or does the tool simply don't analyze the code to that extent?

Comment: @Steve - Yes. I can assign a variable by using FirstOrDefault, and the check if for `null`. But the code above is mostly an example, and I wonder if ReSharper is as clever as it thinks it is, or if it's actually not analyzing the `Any`-part?

Comment: This is like the error emitted by the compiler _use of unassigned variable_ when you have that variable assigned inside an if block that is logically always true. Simply put. Trying to analyze your code to this level is not feasible because the static analyzers should know at compile time what will be the status of your variables at runtime.

Comment: Btw, imagine that `GetItems` returns a reference to a shared array, and another thread updates the `Foo` name from "MyName" to "YourName" just after the `Any` call. What will be the result after `FirstOrDefault`? NRE :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is like the error emitted by the compiler *use of unassigned variable* when you are sure that your variable is assigned inside an if block that is logically always true. Simply put. Trying to analyze your code to this level is not feasible because the static analyzers should know (or better *understand*) at compile time what will be the status of your variables at runtime

```
void Main()
{

    int a;
    Environment.CurrentDirectory = "C:\\temp";
    if(Environment.CurrentDirectory == "C:\\temp")
        a = 1;
    // Error - Use of unassigned variable 
    Console.WriteLine(a);
}
```

Here, the human brain can see that there is no way to not assign the variable, (there are no other threads that mess with the same property, you have checked the reference source about the property behavior) but the compiler should analyze with the same depth the meaning of this code and, at this point in time, we don't have that. The same rules applies to Resharper, they lack the necessary *intelligence* to do everything required (for now)

Comment: Yeah. There is also no guarantee that the property getter will return the same value that has been passed to property setter. Or even if it's a field, there is no guarantee that it will not be changed by another thread between the calls, etc.

Comment: Thank you. It was as I suspected, but I was worried that I missed something.

Answer (score 6):

It is because of `FirstOrDefault`. It returns NULL for classes, if the condition does not match. ReSharper does not take the `Any` in account at this point.

You should replace it with a call to `First`

Comment: This is the correct answer. `FirstOrDefault` is the only thing that matters. The method has an `CanBeNull` annotation, which is why `item` is considered to be possible `null`.